# Show data according to selected city using magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to show all data and categories according to the selected city. For example I have 100 cities and according to that city I will show categories and data on the frontend.

You can see the reference site: `www.skillkindle.com` , `www.justdial.com`.

You can see when I selected a city then according to that particular selected city, all data, categories and products are changed.
Please tell me whether I have to create different stores for 100 cities or there is any other logic to solve this problem as creating multiple stores for 100 cities is a quite lengthy and time taking process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an attribute to filter these information.
With advanced search you'll have a similar result of justdial.com.
It's a basical approach but it works.

Comment: Before to write a your own block sending parameters to advanced search magento could be helpful in learning logics and objects in magento. I'm giving you an approach more than the best solution.